# Is there something like willPresentUIViewController?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to catch the event of presenting a `PopupVC` on `MainVC` which present it.

I'm working on legacy code where `MainVC` is getting called from everywhere and other classes calls for `VC.Present(PopupVC)` and sometime `VC = MainVC` not all the time :\ .

I can't controller all this classes or change them.

I don't have segues.

I need to add a method that will do something every time a popup is presented.

Ideally `MainVC` will have something like `willPresent(viewController)` for every VC it's about to present.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could overwrite the present function in your main viewcontroller to execute code when its called... then call the function on super to actually present the view.